# Delphi, adding digets

Tags: delphi, delphi-7

My textbook says I need to make a donation program with three buttons, each representing a certain amount of money. The "Amount donated" should be shown on a label after I press a button.

For instance if I press the `$10` button, it will say `The total amount raised so far is $10`. And then if I press the `$50` button, the label should caption `The total amount raised so far is $60`. I'm in need of 3 buttons, a `$10, $20` and `$50`.

I don't even know where to start with the coding side!

Here's the starting code:

```
unit AIDSAWARENESS_U;

interface

uses
  Windows, Messages, SysUtils, Variants, Classes, Graphics, Controls, Forms,
  Dialogs, StdCtrls, ExtCtrls;

type
  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    Panel1: TPanel;
    btn10: TButton;
    btn50: TButton;
    btn20: TButton;
    lblOutput: TLabel;
  private
   {private declarations}
  public
   {public declarations}
  end;

var
  Form1: TForm1;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}


end.
```

If you wouldn't mind helping me, it would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
unit AIDSAWARENESS_U;

interface

uses
  Windows, Messages, SysUtils, Variants, Classes, Graphics, Controls, Forms,
  Dialogs, StdCtrls, ExtCtrls;

type
  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    Panel1: TPanel;
    btn10: TButton;
    btn50: TButton;
    btn20: TButton;
    lblOutput: TLabel;
    procedure btnClick(Sender: TObject);
  private
    {private declarations}
    Amount: Integer;
  public
    {public declarations}
  end;

var
  Form1: TForm1;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}

procedure TForm1.btnClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
  Inc(Amount, TButton(Sender).Tag);
  lblOutput.Caption := Format('The total amount raised so far is $%d', [Amount]);
end;

end.
```

Then all you have to do is assign `btnClick()` as the `OnClick` event handler for all three buttons, and set each button's `Tag` property to the desired amount.

Answer (score 4):

Your application has to

- contain 3 buttons with different values (let them name `Value10_Button`, `Value20_Button` and `Value30_Button`)
- contain a label with the current amount (let it name `Amount_Label`)
- `RaiseAmount` if one of the value button is pressed
- `UpdateAmount_Label` if the amount value has changed

Following this we got straight to

```
type
  TForm1 = class( TForm )
    Value10_Button : TButton;
    Value20_Button : TButton;
    Value50_Button : TButton;
    Amount_Label : TLabel;
    procedure Value10_ButtonClick( Sender : TObject );
    procedure Value20_ButtonClick( Sender : TObject );
    procedure Value50_ButtonClick( Sender : TObject );
  private
    FAmount : Currency;
    procedure SetAmount( const Value : Currency );
    procedure UpdateAmount_Label;
    procedure RaiseAmount( const Value : Currency );
  public
    property Amount : Currency read FAmount write SetAmount;
  end;

procedure TForm1.RaiseAmount( const Value : Currency );
begin
  Amount := Amount + Value;
end;

procedure TForm1.SetAmount( const Value : Currency );
begin
  if FAmount <> Value then
  begin
    FAmount := Value;
    UpdateAmount_Label;
  end;
end;

procedure TForm1.UpdateAmount_Label;
begin
  Amount_Label.Caption := Format( 'The total amount raised so far is $%f', [Amount] );
end;

procedure TForm1.Value10_ButtonClick( Sender : TObject );
begin
  RaiseAmount( 10 );
end;

procedure TForm1.Value20_ButtonClick( Sender : TObject );
begin
  RaiseAmount( 20 );
end;

procedure TForm1.Value50_ButtonClick( Sender : TObject );
begin
  RaiseAmount( 50 );
end;
```

As suggested by Remy you can use the `Tag`property of the Buttons, but I prefer to use them in a different way

```
procedure TForm1.Value_ButtonClick( Sender : TObject );
begin
  case ( Sender as TComponent ).Tag of
    1 : RaiseAmount( 10 );
    2 : RaiseAmount( 20 );
    3 : RaiseAmount( 30 );
  end;
end;
```

In a real application I would have a lookup table to get the values from the tag property to get rid of that **magic numbers**

```
procedure TForm1.Value_ButtonClick( Sender : TObject );
begin
  RaiseAmount( GetAmountFromIndex( ( Sender as TComponent ).Tag ) );
end;
```

Comment: I would use a single `OnClick` handler for all three buttons, and use the button's `Tag` property to hold the amounts to pass to `RaiseAmount()`..

Comment: @SirRufo: Not really.  See my answer.

Answer (score 2):

You need to

- Add a way to count the total value (hint field).
- Add event handlers for the buttons, they need to update the value and show the total.

If you don't know how to do that, check your textbook.

Comment: My textbook doesn't explain things like that.

Comment: @link: Then use the Internet, or even trial and error (which is how I learned programming at the age of 12).

Comment: @link: you keep saying your textbook does not explain anything. You really need to find a better textbook. Or forget textbooks and just experiment on your own, and study other people's code. That is how I taught myself.

Comment: @RemyLebeau I wish I could! Its the schools curriculum to use this specific book. Its called "Enjoy delphi, part 1 and 2". Whenever I experiment on my own, I always just get errors and frustration, and I can't ever find anyone else code that has the same use. But thanks for your answers!

Comment: @link: There are plenty of other Delphi books available. If you can't replace the textbook then at least supplement it with another book. But personally, I learned Delphi by studying the VCL's own source code.

Comment: This is one of those South African-only textbooks (10 years old) because South Africa is one of the last places on Earth to be using Delphi in the classroom. I believe it was thrown together on commission for them. You'd be much better served downloading Marco Cantu's free Pascal guide: http://www.marcocantu.com/epascal/  Finding a used copy of some of his other Delphi books might also be useful.

Comment: @RemyLebeau You were able to learn that way because you are a superstar. :-)

Comment: @alcalde Thanks for your answers. By the way, why was my question downvoted so many times?? I know I suck at coding, I don't really have a brain for coding, but the downvotes do kind of make you feel bad :(

Comment: @link, it is downvoted because it lacks any effort of yourself to fix the problem. It looks like a "fix my homework question."  A good question shows effort of the question asker. (And that is exactly why I answered with pointers no real answer. In the end you learn more from trying than from copying.

Comment: @ToonKrijthe Thanks, will try better next time :)