# Incompatible types: 'Integer' and 'procedure, untyped pointer or untyped parameter'

Tags: delphi, delphi-7

I'm getting an error giving a variable a counting value (Don't know if that makes sense).

```
iCount := inc(iCount,1);
```

Here's my code:

```
var
  iCount : Integer;
procedure TForm1.FormActivate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  edtOutput.SelAttributes.size := 10;
  edtOutput.SelAttributes.name := 'Courier';
  edtOutput.Lines.Add(('Name') + #9 + #9 + ('Age') + #9 + #9 + ('Child or adult'));
end;

procedure TForm1.btnOKClick(Sender: TObject);
var
  sName     :String;
  iAge      :Integer;
begin
  iCount := inc(iCount,1);   // <--- HERES THE ERROR
  sName := edtName.text;
  iAge := edtAge.value;
```

When I give `iCount` its value, I get this error :

`Incompatible types: 'Integer' and 'procedure, untyped pointer or untyped parameter'`

oh, and edtOutput is a `RichEdit`.
I have copied it exactly how my textbook says I must (Not the whole program, just the `iCount` thing)

Any advice on how to fix this would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Which textbook told you to use `Inc` like that?

Comment: I really wish you would learn to use the [documentation](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE5/en/System.Inc), and supplement that horrible textbook you use with another one as has been [suggested before](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21721799/delphi-adding-digets#comment32883613_21723575). If you won't bother to try and help yourself at all, it's going to get very tedious for us holding your hand constantly. All versions of Delphi have a help file that covers at least basic information, and D7's was better than most of them. The IDE makes it very easy (F1, or Help from the menu.)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The signature of `inc` is described in the [documentation](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.Inc):

```
procedure Inc(var X: Ordinal; [ N: Integer]); overload;
procedure Inc(var X: Ordinal; [ N: Integer]); overload;
```

In other words it is a procedure that receives the variable to be incremented as a `var` parameter. It is not a function and does not return a value.

Your code should be:

```
inc(iCount);
```

Comment: I just wish the documentation for [`Dec`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE5/en/System.Dec) was accurate. QC'ed a while ago.

Comment: @LURD You can edit the Talk pages in the documentation, and the doc team goes through each change and, in my experience, fixes the issues.  I just edited http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE5/en/Talk:System.Dec for example.  Chances are it'll be fixed soon or for XE6.

Answer (score 4):

`Inc(ICount, 1);` is all you need.

alternative:

```
ICount := ICount + 1;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Inc(iCount); // This increases by one, by default.
Inc(iCount, x); // This increases by x, where x is an integer.
```